# Workflow for checking if item exist in another list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created a workflow that checks if an item exist in another list (List B). The first thing it does is to add an unique ID to the item, if it is a new item. If I am updating an item, the workflow will use this ID to check if the item exists in another list. For this I have created a Variable (Project ID).

I have inserted a condition saying "If List B: Project ID equals Variable: Project ID" (Find the List item field is set to Field Project ID, Value: Variable: Project ID)

This should tricker an action: "Log [%Current Item:Project Number%] already exists in List B", but it doesn't work.

However if I replace the definisions with Title, it works. But if I replace it with Project nr it goes back to not working

(in both cases I haven't changed the Find the List item)

I have added a picture of my workflow below.

[image]

Comment: what are the types of the variable(ProjectID) and  the field (RW-NC:ProjectID) ?

Comment: Variable(ProjectID)  takes the default ID generated by SharePoint and puts a "ID" in front - i.e. ID1234. And the RW-NC:ProjectID is a textfield.

Comment: If I, instead of using ID+generated ID, use  the Title field, it works. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Instead of setting the variable **ProjectID** to the current Items ID field, 
set the **ProjectID** variable to the ***projectID in the other list***, using Find the list Item by setting the ProjectID on the other list with the ProjectID of the Current Item.

[image]

2- then check IF the variable is Empty, if not empty means the item is exists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And now it doesn't work again. I have deleted the workflow and started over. It seems to be another field that is causing the problem.