# update filed another document library with current list input filed column on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, development

Hi SharePoint Developer experts,

We have one document library and one List on SharePoint 2013. Users update list daily base. There are two  column on the list with name as "Document Title" and "Status". On other hand document library, we have nearly 100+ documents with "Document Title", "ID", "Status" etc columns. Our requirement was, when user add or click save option on the "List", items need to check "Document Title" name on the document library, if "Document title" name match, then "Status" data need to update on the document library. Can anyone please help out on the request.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SharePoint Designer workflow for that. Create a workflow on the list that runs when a list item is modified. Let the workflow find the document in the library, using the title (which must be a unique value!!), then write the status from the list item into the document.

Answer (score 1):

Teylyn's reply is correct and have the basic structure. Update list item action has the part to find your required file/item in another list with the identifier. In your scenario, the identifier is the document title.

So the workflow is triggered when item is created/modified and associated with the list. Then we have a the document title value of current item.
[image]

Some workflows examples for your reference:
http://www.benprins.net/2017/03/13/sharepoint-2013-workflow-check-if-list-item-exists/

[Workflow for checking if item exist in another list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237120/workflow-for-checking-if-item-exist-in-another-list)

Comment: @murali, it seems you are not quite familiar about the workflow actions. The update list item action supports updating library files too. It will fetch the library data and find the file has the correct value according to the settings in "Find the list item" part in my screenshot.  For how to use this action, you can have a check on this thread:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/210353ac-d383-417a-9840-235953f962cb/how-do-i-update-on-field-on-second-list-using-sharepoint-designer?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for support. our request has modified. First item will create on SharePoint list with Document title, status, name etc. later on "document" will upload on "Document library". So once file uploaded on document library, then "status" column need to update from existing list on the new document which uploaded. Could you please suggest us.

Comment: @muralikuruva Sounds not like a big change. The key point will be like what i said in the reply, use the document tile to find correct item. Using the update list item to update the status column, that action will handle all the work.

Comment: Sorry Jerry, I am confused, Please explain bit more..

Comment: @muralikuruva, As I am not sure what you mean by "update from existing list on the new document which uploaded". I assume when a new document is uploaded, the list item which has the same document title with the newly uploaded document, the status column need to be updated. If that is you scenario, It is like what I mentioned in the reply, try to play with the update list item action, that is enough to handle it.